# Braces error occur by using 2 foreach in a single if condition

Tags: razor, html

I got braces error when i try to add foreach to get all blocked users detail in else part of if condition.
Here is my code

```
 @if (IsPost && Request["submit"] != null) //Search users engine
   {
       //search query here
        <h2>Searched Users List</h2>
        @foreach (var data in db.Query(searchUser)) 
        {
            pic = @data.ProfileImage;
            userid = @data.UserID;
            fname = @data.FName;
            lname = @data.LName;
        } 
       @if (userid == "") //user not exist
       {

       }
       else
       {
          var id = ""; var blockuserid = "";
          var CheckBlockedUser = "select * from Report where (Sender='" + @WebSecurity.CurrentUserName + "' AND SendedFor='"+Request["userid"]+"') AND IsBlock='1'";
           foreach (var user in db.Query(CheckBlockedUser))
            {
                id = @user.Sender;
                blockuserid = @user.SendedFor;
            }




            }

       }
       </div>
    }
```

Any Idea Where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` loop through which I get the information of all blocked user

```
foreach (var user in db.Query(CheckBlockedUser)) {
   id = @user.Sender;
   blockuserid = @user.SendedFor;
}
```